# How to mount vfat drive on Linux with ownership other than root?

Tags: linux, mount, debian-squeeze

I'm running into trouble mounting an iPod on a newly upgraded Debian Squeeze.
I suspect either a protocol has changed or I've tickled a bug, which I don't know where to report.

I'm trying to mount the iPod so that I have permission to read and write it.
But my efforts come to nothing:

```
    $ sudo mount -v -t vfat -o uid=32074,gid=6202 /dev/sde2 /mnt/dev/sde2 on /mnt type vfat (rw,uid=32074,gid=6202)
    $ ls -l /mnt
    total 80
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Calendars
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Contacts
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Notes
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 16384 Jun 23  2007 Photos
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 16384 Jun 19  2007 iPod_Control
    $ sudo umount /mnt
    $ sudo mount -v -t vfat -o uid=nr,gid=nr /dev/sde2 /mnt     
    /dev/sde2 on /mnt type vfat (rw,uid=32074,gid=6202)
    $ ls -l /mnt
    total 80
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Calendars
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Contacts
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 16384 Jan  1  2000 Notes
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 16384 Jun 23  2007 Photos
    drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 16384 Jun 19  2007 iPod_Control
```

As you see, I've tried both symbolic and numberic IDs, but the files persist in being owned by root (and only writable by root).

The IDs are really mine; I've had the UID since 1993.

```
$ id
uid=32074(nr) gid=6202(nr) groups=6202(nr),0(root),2(bin),4(adm),...
```

I've put an strace at http://pastebin.com/Xue2u9FZ, and the mount(2) call looks good:

```
mount("/dev/sde2", "/mnt", "vfat", MS_MGC_VAL, "uid=32074,gid=6202") = 0
```

Finally, here's my kernel version from `uname -a`:

```
Linux homedog 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Mon Jun 13 04:13:06 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone know if

- I should be doing something different, or
- If there is a workaround, or
- If this is a bug, where it should be reported?

Comment: Do those UIDs and GIDs (31074 and 6202) actually exist on the system? If you type 'id' does it show that you have that UID and GID?

Comment: I apologize - I would like to add a comment but I do not see the link as I usually do. Another suggestion I'd like to add is watching the output of 'strace' on this command - that can be very enlightening of what's going on under the hood. But I agree with the first commenter - check to make sure those UID and GIDs exist. (Although, I believe mount complains if they don't.) Let me give this some more thought.

Comment: @Jeremy: yep, thanks.  Long story, but I've updated the question.

Comment: IDs checked, strace provided, also gave kernel version.  If you have some ideas I'll be delighted.

Comment: Ok - strace shows nothing unusual. Try this - it's a super-duper long shot, but I don't believe it will hurt. Instead of 'uid' and 'gid' arguments, try 'setuid' and 'setgid'. The reason I suggest this is that for a separate filesystem type, these options control the owner/group of files and directories WITHIN the filesystem, not just the root of the fs itself. MAYBE (but I don't ever remember this being the case), you'll get epic-lucky and those options actually do work for vfat. I'm 99.99% doubtful, but always worth a shot. I'll try to think of anything else.

Comment: Also, something that keeps coming back to me. Mount, without UID or GID arguments, should assigned ownerships to the UID of whoever performed the mount command. I'd be very interested to see what would happen if you set up mount access to the 'nr' user, then did an su - over to the 'nr' account, then performed the mount.

Comment: Quick question - when you generated the output above, what user were you running these commands as? In other words, what user was running the command 'ls -l /mnt' ?

Comment: Perhaps see [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/43634/how-to-mount-external-vfat-drive-as-user); basically, add `user` as an option in `/etc/fstab` and then mount without `sudo`.

Comment: @Handyman5: that's my normal way of doing business.  Same outcome.

Comment: running as user `nr`.

Comment: Why are you in root group?  And is adm group equivalent of wheel?  Does being in the root group not counteract the whole concept of running as normal and elevating as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the machine made the problem go away.

I think I will leave the question since it seems that it does in fact show how to mount a vfat drive on Linux with ownership  other than root.
But if someone thinks I should delete the question please let me know.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at pmount(1), which allows for normal users to mount removable drives.